# Product of compact subsets of a topological group is compact

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, topological-groups

I need to show that if $G$ is a topological group and $A,B\subseteq G$ are compact subsets, then $AB$ is compact.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Tychonoff theorem and the continuity of the map $$G\times G\rightarrow G$$
$$(a,b)\mapsto ab$$.